# Restricting table row in SQL Reporting 2008

Tags: sql, reporting, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I need to restrict the number of rows in my tablix, and have the left overs go to another page and also be restricted to the same amount and so on....

So my sample dataset has 2 records, to test I added a Grouping Expression as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

```
=int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/1)
```

...and set page breaks

this worked successfully, with the first record displayed on its own page and subsequent record displayed on a new page...

Howver when I choose to restrict the no of records to 12 e.g.

```
=int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/12)
```

I'd expect to see those 2 records displayed on the first page, though i only see one of them...

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Still stuck on this issue, any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thought Id come back and let others know what I had done wrong here, it might help someone.

I was incorreclty applying the expression to the details row... you have to right click the details row then Click Add Group -> Parent Group and apply the expression there.